# onsen-ui 特定のページからのpopPageのみpostpopを行いたい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

onsen-uiのnavigatorを利用しての画面遷移で詰まりました。
初心者のため、使い方から間違っているのかもしれまん。

下記のようなコードがあり、コントローラーAでmyNavigatorにpostpopのイベントをセットしています。
このときに、b.htmlとc.htmlのどちらでmyNavigator.popPage()を実行してもアラートが表示されてしまいます。
popPageでa.htmlに戻った時のみpostpopを発火させる方法はありますでしょうか？

ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

```
//controller
module.controller('A', function() {
  myNavigator.on("postpop", function() {
     alert("test");
  });
});

module.controller('B', function() {});
module.controller('C', function() {});

//a.html
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
   <ons-page ng-controller="A">
      <div ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('b.html')">ページB</div>
   </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

//b.html
   <ons-page ng-controller="B">
      <div ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()">Aに戻る</div>
      <div ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('c.html')">ページC</div>
   </ons-page>

//c.html
   <ons-page ng-controller="C">
      <div ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()">Bに戻る</div>
   </ons-page>
```

Comment: oTakさん、ありがとうございました！
おかげさまで解決しました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.html(親)`に戻るのみなら`e.navigator.pages.length == 1`でよいのですが、`b.html`から`a.html`に戻る場合なら`e.leavePage.name == "b.html"`の条件も必要となります。

```
myNavigator.on("postpop", function(e) {
    if (e.navigator.pages.length == 1) {
        if (e.leavePage.name == "b.html") {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
});
```